# Regular expression for chess Time Control extraction from pgn

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression to extract:
[TimeControl "900+2"] from a pgn. I will store the game time in seconds and the increment in seconds as 2 variables.

I tried:
time_control_match = re.search(r'[TimeControl "^\d{5}+\d"]', pgn_content)

Here is the complete solution:

```
# Using the regex pattern
time_control_match = re.search(r'\[TimeControl "(\d+)\+(\d+)"\]', pgn_content)
if time_control_match:
    initial_time, increment = time_control_match.groups()
    return int(initial_time), int(increment)
else:
    return None, None
```

Comment: time_control_match = re.search(r'\[TimeControl "^\d{5}+\d"]', pgn_content)

Comment: Please add your attempt to your question, we will try to help you starting from there.

Comment: Look up what `^` means and what regex metacharacters (like `[` and `+`) are, and how to match them in a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is something along the lines of:

`\[TimeControl "\d+\+\d+"\]`

This will match the block, however you will have to parse the string again to extract the two integers.

Instead you can use a regex with capture groups:

`\[TimeControl "(\d+)\+(\d+)"\]`

and then use `time_control_match.groups()` to return a tuple of just the values you are looking for.

Comment: you are right, my solution would have captured strings as well and yours captures only digits (although the probability of have strings is very close to 0). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick regex search for the TimeControl itself: `^\[TimeControl ".+"\]$`

If you are looking for something more specific where you are matching the digits, also here it is: `^\[TimeControl "\d+\+\d+"\]$`

Have a look at the this site https://www.regular-expressions.info/
Read up on meta characters (the ones you need to escape) in regex and quantifiers, character classes.

Comment: I found this finally: time_control_match = re.search(r'\[TimeControl ".*\+.*"\]', pgn_content) with <re.Match object; span=(213, 234), match='[TimeControl "900+2"]'>